# Kotlin linked list: How to check if given list is sorted (descending)

Tags: sorting, kotlin, linked-list

I am trying to write a function, which determines if the given linked list is sorted (descending).

Given list 1: 8 -> 5 -> 3 -> null (true)

Given list2: 8 -> 6 -> 10 -> 3 -> null (false)

Given list3: 8 -> 8 -> 3 -> null (true)

Here is my current approach:

```
class Linkedlist {
    var head: Node? = null

    data class Node(val value: Int, var next: Node?)

    // Current approach
    fun isListSorted(): Boolean {
        // If list is empty
        if (head == null) return true

        var curr = head

        while(curr != null) {
           curr = curr.next

           if (curr?.value!! <= curr?.next?.value!!) return false else return true
        }
        return true
   }
}
```

And here my main:

```
fun main() {
    val list1 = Linkedlist()
    list1.append(8)
    list1.append(5)
    list1.append(3)

    val list2 = Linkedlist()
    list2.append(8)
    list2.append(6)
    list2.append(10)
    list2.append(3)

    val list3 = Linkedlist()
    list3.append(8)
    list3.append(8)
    list3.append(3)

}
```

I get a NullPointerException. What am I doing wrong? I appreciate every help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of Kotlin's most attractive features is null-safety. You don't get NullPointerExceptions unless you use the `!!` operator. The `!!` operator should only be used when you have checked your code and you logically know that at that point in code, the parameter cannot be null, but the logic to figure that out is too much for the compiler.

You use the `!!` operator in a place where the value of `curr` very well *can* be null. You set `curr = curr.next`, and `next` will be `null` at the tail of your list, so `curr` will be `null` when you use the `!!` operator on it.

This line of code wouldn't make sense anyway, because you return from both branches of your `if`/`else` here, so you cannot possibly ever check more than one node of your list.

A possible way to do this:

```
fun isListSorted(): Boolean {
    var curr = head ?: return true

    while(true) {
        val next = curr.next ?: return true
        if (curr.value < next.value)
            return false
        curr = next
    }
}
```

Comment: It works now, thank you very much. But could you explain your code a bit? What does this "?: return true" exactly mean and when will the while loop end?

Comment: This is so we can make`curr` and `next` non-nullable parameters, because if they were null, we go ahead and return true. The elvis `?:` operator lets the function return immediately if the value is null. Then there is no need for using `!!` because we have properly handled the case where a value is null. So the `while` loop runs continually until it encounters the null tail or it encounters an unsorted `next`.

Comment: But what if the list is sorted? I don't exactly get when the while loop breaks out except when it encounters an unsorted next?

Comment: If it reaches the last element without encountering an out-of-order element, `curr.next` will be `null`, so it will reach the `return true` statement.